Nuxt private variables are not getting read on production enviornment
I am working with Nuxt3. And here is my public and private variables definition in nuxt.config.ts-
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: { myPublicVar: '' },
    myPrivateVar: ''
  }
})

On localhost, my .env file looks something like this-
NUXT_MY_PRIVATE_VAR: 'privateValue'
NUXT_PUBLIC_MY_PUBLIC_VAR: 'publicValue'

When I test on my localhost-
On client side, let's say in app.vue, it works fine-
const config = useRuntimeConfig()
console.log(config.public.myPublicVar) // prints 'publicValue'

On the server side let's say in api/users.ts, it works fine-
const config = useRuntimeConfig()
console.log(config.myPrivateVar) // prints 'privateValue'

Now, I host this, Nuxt application on the AWS server, and manage my secrets on AWS secret manager. I used the exact names for the environmental variable as mentioned above. However, on production, the public variables work perfectly, and the private variables print nothing. Looks like environmental variables are not overriding the values of runtimeConfig ( it should work like public variable does)
When I test on production-
const config = useRuntimeConfig()
console.log(config.myPrivateVar) // prints ''

I followed the documentation that env variables with the prefix NUXT_PUBLIC_ and private variables with NUXT_ can override the values in runtimeConfig. I also followed the blog written on the same concept.
Can anyone please guide me, on what must be happening here?

Do you have the issue if you try to host it elsewhere like Netlify? Just to be sure that this is an AWS issue.

I haven't tried yet, but yeah good catch. I will try this and let you know ASAP.

It was an AWS cache issue, I cleared the cache and it worked. Thanks.
